# How to flatten inner tuples in a list containing tuples of a two-item tuple and a single item

Tags: python, list

I want to know if there is any efficient way to convert a list containing tuples of a two-item tuple and a single item into a flattened list or NumPy array?

```
list = [((-1, -1), -1), ((-1, -1), 0), ((-1, -1), 1), ((-1, -1), 2), ...]
```

The result I want is:

```
new_list = [[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, 2], ...]
```

So far, I have tried to use

```
new_list = [item for i in list for item in i]
```

But the result is comes out as:

```
[(-1, -1), -1, (-1, -1), 0, (-1, -1), 1, (-1, -1), 2, ...]
```

When I tried to remove the nested tuple, I got the error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: That result is not really flat, either. Also, are the tuples always structured the same?

Comment: Yes, it will always be the same. @tobias_k

Answer (score 8):

Since the structure of each of the tuples seems to be `((a, b), c)`, you can just use a list comprehension with tuple-unpacking:

```
>>> lst = [((-1, -1), -1), ((-1, -1), 0), ((-1, -1), 1), ((-1, -1), 2)]
>>> [[a, b, c] for ((a, b), c) in lst]
[[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 0], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a shorter one:

```
[[*x, y] for x, y in lst]
```

Comment: Fun fact: I wrote this before the other two answers were posted, then saw those, and was sure that at least one of them would look at the other's and be like "Ah right, we can do that", and combine them to end up with this. Then that didn't happen. Then Mad edited and I thought it was to add this, but no, it was to add the second, *more* subscribing solution :-). And then I was like ok, if they don't, then I will.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the structure of the list (more or less). You're really flattening the nested elements, not the list itself. Unpacking is one simple way to go

```
new_lst = [[*x[0], x[1]] for x in lst]
```

Another is just explicit references:

```
new_lst = [[x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1]] for x in lst]
```

Comment: Thanks! I learn another solution to solve my problem now

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming `x = [((-1, -1), -1), ((-1, -1), 0), ((-1, -1), 1), ((-1, -1), 2), ...]`

```
new_list = [list(i[0])+[i[1]] for i in x]
```